# Views slideshow numbered pager

Tags: 7, views

Im using Drupal 7, and I am trying to make a slide show with a numbered pager like the one shown in [this page](http://www.usbank.com/en/PersonalHome.cfm). I added PHP code in Views, thinking I could simple put PHP code, but the problem is that it is not producing the expected result.

I used this code, which is supposed to print "1 2 3 4", and that instead prints "1 1 1 1."

```
$i = 0; 
$i++; 
echo $i;
```

In this code I tried using one of the variables, and I think I am on the right track with this one, but it prints "10 9 8 7," while I want it prints "1 2 3 4."

```
$i = 0; 
$i = $row->field_image; 
echo $i;
```

I know that this is probably something simple, but I can't figure out how to save my life; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing. Where do you put that code (default argument?) and i'm assuming that 'mycode_iterator_count' stands for something else. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you put it in global php null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code you wrote doesn't work because, all times it is invoked

- it initializes `$i` to 0
- it increments `$i` by 1
- it prints the value of `$1`

Because the first step, the result is always 1.
To get a result that is different in any cases, the code should be similar to the following.

```
$i = variable_get('mycode_iterator_count', 0) + 1;  
echo $i;
variable_set('mycode_iterator_count', $i);
```

The code is not optimized, and probably there is a better way to write the code; although, the code works, as it will print a different number every time it is invoked.
As the code is passed to `eval()`, using a static variable would not probably serve to the purpose because the static variable will probably be reset to 0 every time the code is executed through `eval()`. Probably the code would work even if it would use a global variable.

```
global $i;

if (empty($i)) {
  $i = 1;
}

echo $i++;
```

Answer (score 5):

Much easier way:

1. Add "Global: View result counter" Field
2. Exclude it from Display
3. In Slideshow setting: choose that field as the Pager Type

Answer (score 2):

Embedding PHP inside the view is a bad idea. PHP Views should be avoided. Instead I have come up with the following which works with default views:

1. Click "add" on the fields box.
2. Add a "Global: Math expression" field to your fields.
3. In the "Expression" field enter [expression] + 1
4. Click "Exclude from display".
5. Set your pager field to be the expression.